# MVC 5.1.2 EditorFor htmlAttributes

Tags: editorfor

This looks simple enough:

@Html.EditorFor(m =>m.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, }

however, the emitted page does not have this class applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

this seems to work for me, you have a comma at the end there and failed to close the paranthesis correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The MVC Editor helper is expecting an `additionalViewData` object as that argument. This has been better handled in ASP.Net MVC 5.1 but for the time being, swapping your `EditorFor` to a `TextBoxFor` should do the trick nicely.